# Ajax does not display the result from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have an issue with my ajax request and I can't figure out what is wrong, in console there is no error...

Here is my javascript file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 done(); 
});

function done(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  updates();
  done();
  }, 50000);
}

function updates() {
 $.getJSON("sedinte.php", function(data){
  $("#results").empty();
  $(".pagination").empty();

  $.each(data.result, function() {$("#results").append("<tr class='"+this['aclass']+"'><td>"+this['object']+"</td><td>"+this['date']+"</td><td>"+this['amount']+"</td><td>"+this['paid']+"</td></tr>");
   });
  $.each(data.pagination, function() {
    $("ul.pagination").append(this['controls']);
   });
 });
}

$("#btnAdd").click(function(){  
 $.post(
  $("#addForm").attr("action"), $("#addForm :input").serializeArray(), function(info) {
   $("#feedback").html(info);  
 });
 clearInput();
});

$("#addForm").submit(function(){
 return false;
});

function clearInput() {
 $("#addForm :input").each( function() {
    $(this).val(' ');
 });
}
```

Here is my file I want to request:

```html
<?php
     
    #Get the total number of rows
    $rows = $db->getTotalRows("sedinte");
    
    #Set number of result to show on each page
    $page_rows = 10;
    
    #Get the last page
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
    
    #Make sure the last page is not below 1
    if($last <1)
    {
        $last = 1;
    }
    $pagenum = 1; #Default page
    
    #Get page number from URL vars if it is pressent, else it is = 1
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
    }
    
    #Make sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our last page
    if($pagenum < 1)
    {
        $pagenum = 1;
    }
    else if($pagenum > $last)
    {
        $pagenum = $last;
    }
    
    #This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen page number
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows . ',' .$page_rows;
    
    #This is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying limit
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sedinte ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
    $query = mysqli_query($db->Conn(), $sql);
       
    #Enstablish the pagination controls variable
    $paginationCtrls = null;
    #<li><a href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    #If there is more than 1 page worth of results
    if($last != 1)
    {
        if($pagenum > 1)
        {
            $previous = $pagenum - 1;
            $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=' .$previous.'">&laquo;</a></li>';
            
            #Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
            for($i = $pagenum - 4; $i < $pagenum; $i++)
            {
                if($i > 0)
                {
                    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=' .$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        
        #Render the current page
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li class="active"><a href="">'.$pagenum.'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
        
        #Render clickable number lnks that should appear on the right of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++)
        {
          $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=' .$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
          if($i >= $pagenum+4)
          {
            break;
          }  
        }
        
        if($pagenum != $last)
        {
            $next = $pagenum + 1;
            $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=' .$next.'">&raquo;</a></li>';
        }
        
    }
$paginationArray = array();
array_push($paginationArray, array('controls' => $paginationCtrls));

$listTest = null;
$resultArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    //$id = $row['id'];
    $obiect = $row['obiect'];
 $data = $row['data'];
    $suma = $row['suma'];    
 $achitat = $row['achitat'];
        if($achitat == 'Da')
    {
        $active_class= null;
    }
    else
    {        
        $active_class= "danger";
    }   
    array_push($resultArray, array('object' => $obiect,
                              'date' => $data,
                              'amount' => $suma,
                              'paid' => $achitat,
                              'aclass' => $active_class
                               ));
    

   /*
    $listTest .='   <tr class="'.$active_class.'">                                 
                        <td>'.$obiect.'</td>
                        <td>'.$data.'</td>
                        <td>'.$suma.'</td>
                        <td>'.$achitat.'</td> 
                    </tr>';*/
  
}
echo json_encode(array("result" => $resultArray, "pagination" => $paginationArray));
mysqli_close($db->Conn());
?>
```

And here is my index file:

```html
<?php
 require 'includes/settings.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sedinte</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
  <div role="tabpanel">
  
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#sedinte" aria-controls="sedinte" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Vezi Sedinte</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#adauga" aria-controls="adauga" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Adauga Sedinta</a></li>
    </ul>
  
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="sedinte">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
         <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>  Buget: 460 RON</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Data: <?php echo date('D d M Y');?></h4>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr>        
         <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Obiect</th>
         <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Data</th>
         <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Suma</th>
         <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Achitat</th>         
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="results">
        <?php //echo $listTest;?>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class="pagination">
     <?php //echo $paginationCtrls;?>
    </ul>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="adauga">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <form action="add.php" method="post" id="addForm">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="obiect">Obiect</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxObiect" placeholder="M, L, R">
          <!-- 
          <select name="boxObiect" class="form-control">
            <option>Matematica</option>
            <option>Romana</option>
            <option>Logica</option>        
          </select>
          -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="data">Data: </label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxData" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="radioAchitat">Achitat: </label>
             <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radioAchitat" id="radioAchitat" value="Da"> Da
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radioAchitat" id="radioAchitat" value="Nu" checked="checked"> Nu
          </label>
            </div>
         
            <button type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Adauga</button>
           </form>          
          </div>
         </div>
        <div id="feedback"></div>
              
       </div>       
      </div>
 
     </div>
  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My data from the database is not showing... just the main template.
Please help me!

Comment: The code is long to test. Maybe try first simple ajax request, just get something and receive it back. see if it works or not. then test the MySQL query separately.  then if both work you will be more close to what is wrong.

Comment: @batz I have a simple ajax request when I am adding a new item and is working just perfect, and the  Mysql queryies separately are working like charm... that's why I can't get it. I don't receive any error, but my data still not shows up.

Comment: 1. Could be you forgot to include the Connect info in the Ajax file?
2. Could be PHP is not set to display all errors?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't kow what's the problem because i did not read the full code, but that is a bug that i found so you can correct that and can try again :), i hope it will work, Thanks

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("result" => $resultArray, "pagination" => $paginationArray));
mysqli_close($db->Conn());
```

Comment: I have tried it, but nothing is changing, anyway thank you very much for support.